# how do i list properties in a vertex usin SQL?

Tags: sql, orientdb

i have a vertex called "users" like

`+------+------+-----+
|  cc  | name | cod |
+------+------+-----+
| 0001 | jhon | 123 |
+------+------+-----+
| 0002 | paul | 567 |
+------+------+-----+`

i want a list with just vertex properties,
something like:

`+------+
|  cc  |
+------+
| name |
+------+ 
| cod  |
+------+`

i know that in sql normally people use: 
`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
or
`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

but i dont know how do i get this result in orientdb,
**how do i list properties in a vertex with SQL?**

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select expand(properties) from (select expand(classes) from metadata:schema) where name = "<class-name>"
```

---

Found it here: [Get all used fieldnames of schema-hybrid Class in Orientdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787637/get-all-used-fieldnames-of-schema-hybrid-class-in-orientdb)

---

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: that sql query on orientdb report no error, but a empty answer, i try changing the "<class-name>" with my classes and orientdb classes like "OUser" and "OIdentity" or "ORole" and still empty :(

Comment: It's working for me. I've added some screenshots.  I'm on v2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

To see the properties of a class execute this command by the OrientDB console:

```
info class 'class - name'
```

this is the output:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: I don't think it exists!

Comment: Worth to mention that the `info class <class name>` command works only in orientdb console. So it won't work in Studio.